# ls - how to output only filename, date (ISO 8601) to CSV?

Tags: linux, date, csv, awk, ls

I have a number of files in a directory:

`img1_1.jpg, img1_2.jpg ... img1_199.jpg, img1_2000.jpg`

I would like to output a listing of these files to a csv containing only: `filename, datetime`

For example:
`img1_116.jpg,2011-05-25 22:00:49.000000000 +0000`

I am trying:

`ls -l --time-style="full-iso" img1* | awk '/^-/ && $1=$1' OFS=","`

But the date/time keeps getting split up due to the space in the date/time format:

`img1_116.jpg,2011-05-25,22:00:49.000000000,+0000`

(This is just an example, my actual output still contains the rights, user, group etc)

Is there a way to:

1. Export the CSV without splitting the date/time format?
2. Have `ls` and select only filename and date/time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does something like `ls -l --time-style=full-iso | awk '/^-/ {printf "%s,%s %s\n",$NF,$6,$7}'` do what you want?

Comment: Precisely on the dot. And quickly at that, thank you :) So quickly I can't even accept the answer yet.

Comment: One word to say - pro.